# Flash content covering drop-down menus

Tags: flash, google-chrome, safari, drop-down-menu, wmode

I have a CSS drop-down menu and just below is a Flash Video (embeded with YouTube code). The Flash video covers my drop down, but only in Safari.

I have played around with the z-index, and I have tried both "opaque" and "transparent" for wmode (which has always fixed this for me in the past).

Any ideas on how to stop the video from covering my drop-downs?

Comment: This is also happening in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Well it took a lot of searching, but it would appear the issue was that there was no "type" attribute for the object.

Adding this:

type="application/x-shockwave-flash"

fixed the issue.

Also seems to be that wmode="opaque" is less processor intensive, so don't use "transparent" unless you actually need the transparency.

Comment: That's why flash files should be embedded using SWFObject. It solves most cross browser issues and more.